# enable-asserts could not find command

Tags: flutter, dart

```bash
"G:/Flutter Learning/flutter install/dart-sdk/bin/dart.exe" --enable-asserts "G:\Flutter Learning\flutter install\dart-sdk"
Could not find a command named "G:\Flutter Learning\flutter install\dart-sdk".

Usage: dart <command|dart-file> [arguments]

Global options:
-v, --verbose               Show additional command output.
    --version               Print the Dart SDK version.
    --enable-analytics      Enable analytics.
    --disable-analytics     Disable analytics.
    --suppress-analytics    Disallow analytics for this `dart *` run without changing the analytics configuration.
-h, --help                  Print this usage information.

Available commands:
  analyze    Analyze Dart code in a directory.
  compile    Compile Dart to various formats.
  create     Create a new Dart project.
  devtools   Open DevTools (optionally connecting to an existing application).
  doc        Generate API documentation for Dart projects.
  fix        Apply automated fixes to Dart source code.
  format     Idiomatically format Dart source code.
  info       Show diagnostic information about the installed tooling.
  pub        Work with packages.
  run        Run a Dart program.
  test       Run tests for a project.

Run "dart help <command>" for more information about a command.
See https://dart.dev/tools/dart-tool for detailed documentation.

Process finished with exit code 64
```